# Change Order of Created Concatenated Column Variables

Tags: sql-server

Here is my question - is there a way I can edit my code so that the RequestedDateTime1 time from query 1 remains aligned with the its corresponding EventDisplay1 from query 1?

Below is how I arrived with this question.

I have the following code:

```
SELECT [Financial Number], [Depart Date & Time], 
             (Cast(Year([Arrival Date & Time]) as nvarchar) +'-'+ Cast (Month([Arrival Date & Time]) as nvarchar)) as Yr_Mon,
             [Event 1 Display],
             [Event 1 Personnel - Completed],
             [Requested 1 Date & Time],
             [Completed 1 Date & Time],
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Financial Number] ORDER BY [Event 1 Display]) AS RB,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Financial Number] ORDER BY [Requested 1 Date & Time]) AS RN,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION by [Financial Number] ORDER BY [Completed 1 Date & Time]) AS RM,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION by [Financial Number] ORDER BY [Event 1 Personnel - Completed]) AS RO,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION by [Financial Number] ORDER BY [Arrival Date & Time]) as AD,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION by [Financial Number] ORDER BY [Depart Date & Time]) as DT
FROM [ED_Dispo_Events_Using_Event_1 Triage Level 3] AS ED
```

Which produces results that look like the following (this is abbreviated for space reasons):

```
[Financial Number] [Depart Date & Time] .. EventDisplay1 RequestedDateTime1
      1              2018-01-01 10:19:11     EP Exam     2018-01-01 11:19 
      1              2018-01-01 10:19:11     Discharge   2018-01-01 12:20
      2              2018-01-01 13:49:11     EP Exam     2018-01-01 12:20
```

I then add a query to the data query 1 produces:

```
Select [Financial Number], 
   MIN(CASE DT WHEN 1 THEN [Depart Date & Time] END) AS [Depart Date & 
   Time1],
   MIN(CASE RB WHEN 1 THEN [Event 1 Display] END) AS EventDisplay1,
   MIN(CASE RB WHEN 2 THEN [Event 1 Display] END) AS EventDisplay2,
   MIN(CASE RB WHEN 3 THEN [Event 1 Display] END) AS EventDisplay3,
   MIN(CASE RO WHEN 1 THEN [Event 1 Personnel - Completed] END) AS 
   EventPersonnelCompleted1,
   MIN(CASE RO WHEN 2 THEN [Event 1 Personnel - Completed] END) AS 
   EventPersonnelCompleted2,
   MIN(CASE RO WHEN 3 THEN [Event 1 Personnel - Completed] END) AS 
   EventPersonnelCompleted3,
   MIN(CASE RN WHEN 1 THEN [Requested 1 Date & Time] END) AS RequestedDateTime1,
   MIN(CASE RN WHEN 2 THEN [Requested 1 Date & Time] END) AS RequestedDateTime2,
   MIN(CASE RN WHEN 3 THEN [Requested 1 Date & Time] END) AS RequestedDateTime3,
   MIN(CASE RM WHEN 1 THEN [Completed 1 Date & Time] END) AS CompletedDateTime1,
   MIN(CASE RM WHEN 2 THEN [Completed 1 Date & Time] END) AS CompletedDateTime2,
   MIN(CASE RM WHEN 3 THEN [Completed 1 Date & Time] END) AS CompletedDateTime3,

  FROM
 (

SELECT [Financial Number], [Depart Date & Time], 
             (Cast(Year([Arrival Date & Time]) as nvarchar) +'-'+ Cast (Month([Arrival Date & Time]) as nvarchar)) as Yr_Mon,
             [Event 1 Display],
             [Event 1 Personnel - Completed],
             [Requested 1 Date & Time],
             [Completed 1 Date & Time],
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Financial Number] ORDER BY [Event 1 Display]) AS RB,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Financial Number] ORDER BY [Requested 1 Date & Time]) AS RN,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION by [Financial Number] ORDER BY [Completed 1 Date & Time]) AS RM,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION by [Financial Number] ORDER BY [Event 1 Personnel - Completed]) AS RO,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION by [Financial Number] ORDER BY [Arrival Date & Time]) as AD,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION by [Financial Number] ORDER BY [Depart Date & Time]) as DT
  FROM [ED_Dispo_Events_Using_Event_1 Triage Level 3] AS ED
   )sub group by [Financial Number]
```

This query produces results that concatenate each row so each row is one unique Financial Number; however in doing so it messes up the alignment of the RequestedDateTime1 variable with the EventDisplay1 variable. For example, using the sample data above, the RequestedDateTime1 of 2018-01-01 12:20, which was aligned with DISCHARGE is now aligned with EP EXAM. I believe this is because the code orders the newly created EventDisplay1, EventDisplay2, EventDisplay3 variables in alphabetical order.

Example Results which are incorrect because the Discharge RequestedDateTime1 is aligned with the EP RequestedDateTime1:

```
 [Financial Number]   [Depart Date & Time]  EventDisplay1    EventDisplay2 RequestedDateTime1 RequestedDateTime2
        1             2018-01-01 10:19:11    Discharge         EP Exam 2018-01-01 11:19  2018-01-01 12:20
```

Long story short, is there a way I can edit my code so that the RequestedDateTime1 time from query 1 remains aligned with the its corresponding EventDisplay1 from query 1?

Desired Results:

```
   [Financial Number]   [Depart Date & Time]  EventDisplay1    EventDisplay2 RequestedDateTime1 RequestedDateTime2
        1             2018-01-01 10:19:11     EP Exam        Discharge     2018-01-01 11:19  2018-01-01 12:20
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting mixed up with your row numbering. What you want to do is have one column of ordering - a single ROW_NUMBER statement that will give a number to the row. Then you want to pull all values when this row = 1, all values when this row = 2 etc... This way your data will make sense. All values from rowNumber1 will display as EventDisplay1, RequestedDateTime1 etc.

Updated query:

```
Select [Financial Number], 
   MIN(CASE DT WHEN 1 THEN [Depart Date & Time] END) AS [Depart Date & 
   Time1],
   MIN(CASE RN WHEN 1 THEN [Event 1 Display] END) AS EventDisplay1,
   MIN(CASE RN WHEN 2 THEN [Event 1 Display] END) AS EventDisplay2,
   MIN(CASE RN WHEN 3 THEN [Event 1 Display] END) AS EventDisplay3,
   MIN(CASE RN WHEN 1 THEN [Event 1 Personnel - Completed] END) AS 
   EventPersonnelCompleted1,
   MIN(CASE RN WHEN 2 THEN [Event 1 Personnel - Completed] END) AS 
   EventPersonnelCompleted2,
   MIN(CASE RN WHEN 3 THEN [Event 1 Personnel - Completed] END) AS 
   EventPersonnelCompleted3,
   MIN(CASE RN WHEN 1 THEN [Requested 1 Date & Time] END) AS RequestedDateTime1,
   MIN(CASE RN WHEN 2 THEN [Requested 1 Date & Time] END) AS RequestedDateTime2,
   MIN(CASE RN WHEN 3 THEN [Requested 1 Date & Time] END) AS RequestedDateTime3,
   MIN(CASE RN WHEN 1 THEN [Completed 1 Date & Time] END) AS CompletedDateTime1,
   MIN(CASE RN WHEN 2 THEN [Completed 1 Date & Time] END) AS CompletedDateTime2,
   MIN(CASE RN WHEN 3 THEN [Completed 1 Date & Time] END) AS CompletedDateTime3,

  FROM
 (

SELECT [Financial Number], [Depart Date & Time], 
             (Cast(Year([Arrival Date & Time]) as nvarchar) +'-'+ Cast (Month([Arrival Date & Time]) as nvarchar)) as Yr_Mon,
             [Event 1 Display],
             [Event 1 Personnel - Completed],
             [Requested 1 Date & Time],
             [Completed 1 Date & Time],
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Financial Number] ORDER BY [Event 1 Display]) AS RN --choose whichever column you want to determine ordering here...
  FROM [ED_Dispo_Events_Using_Event_1 Triage Level 3] AS ED
   )sub group by [Financial Number]
```

Comment: this won't work at all -- he wants different top three based on different orderings... you have changed it to just one orderiing.

Comment: @Hogan No he doesn't - he wants DateTime of the first event associated with the first etc.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are not accounting for NULL and you are using MIN not max.
Cast the values to string if you want to be able to have a valid value for null:

Replace every line that looks like this

```
MIN(CASE RB WHEN 1 THEN [Event 1 Display] END) AS EventDisplay1,
```

with something that looks like this

```
COALESCE(CAST(MAX(CASE WHERE RB = 1 THEN [Event 1 Display] ELSE NULL END) AS VARCHAR(20)),
         '    -- NO VALUE --  ') AS EventDisplay1,
```

Comment: thank you! I think I may have explained by issue incorrectly, as FizzBuzz's solution worked. I do have an additional question though, is there a way to make 'EP Exam' appear as EventDisplay1 when that patient also has 'discharge'- when there are both events, it appears SQL sets 'EP Exam' as EventDisplay1 because of alphabetization.

Comment: @greg there are better ways to do it if that is what you want.  you do understand that everything is ordered by [event 1 display] whatever that is -- so you are getting the first request timestamp in that column or the first completed timestamp in that column

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Question was not so clear but this is not the issue OP is struggling with.

Comment: @FizzBuzz -- I think the odds are better that he was wrong about your solution solving the problem and there are much faster ways to write the query if he wants the results your query gives.